# Solve $\tan^22x+\cot^22x+2\tan2x+2\cot2x=6$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve $\tan^22x+\cot^22x+2\tan2x+2\cot2x=6$

My attempt is as follows:

$$\left(\tan^22x+\dfrac{1}{\tan^22x}+2\right)+1+2\left(\tan2x+\dfrac{1}{\tan2x}\right)=9$$
$$\left(\left(\tan2x+\dfrac{1}{\tan2x}\right)+1\right)^2=9$$
$$\left(\left(\tan2x+\dfrac{1}{\tan2x}\right)+1\right)=\pm3$$
$$\left(\tan2x+\dfrac{1}{\tan2x}=2\right) \text { or } \left(\tan2x+\dfrac{1}{\tan2x}\right)=-4$$

$$\left(\tan2x-1=0\right) \text { or } \left(\tan^22x+4\tan2x+1=0\right)$$

$$\left(\tan2x=1\right) \text { or } \left(\tan2x=\dfrac{-4\pm\sqrt{12}}{2}\right)$$
$$\left(2x=n\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) \text { or } \left(\tan2x=-2\pm\sqrt{3}\right)$$
$$\left(x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}\right) \text { or } \left(\tan2x=-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)\right) \text { or } \left(\tan2x=-\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)\right)$$
$$\left(x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}\right) \text { or } \left(2x=n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right) \text { or } \left(\tan2x=\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)\right)$$

$$\left(x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}\right) \text { or } \left(x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}\right) \text { or } \left(2x=n\pi+\dfrac{7\pi}{12}\right)$$

**$$\left(x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}\right) \text { or } \left(x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}\right) \text { or } \left(x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{7\pi}{24}\right)$$**

We also have $\sin2x\ne0 \text { and } \cos2x\ne0$

$$x\ne\dfrac{n\pi}{2} \text { and } x\ne\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}{4}$$

**Lets check for first solution**

$$x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}$$
$$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}=\dfrac{m\pi}{2}$$
$$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}=\dfrac{m\pi}{2}$$
$$4n-4m=-1$$

**This is not possible as even - even cannot give odd**

$$x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}$$
$$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}=\dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}{4}$$

$$\dfrac{n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{8}=\dfrac{(2m+1)}{4}$$
$$4n+1=4m+2$$
$$4n-4m=1$$

**This is not possible as even - even cannot be odd**

Hence $x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}$ is valid for $\forall  n\in I$

**Lets check for second solution**

$$x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}$$
$$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}=\dfrac{m\pi}{2}$$
$$12n-12m=1$$

**This is not possible as even - even cannot be odd**

$$x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}$$
$$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}=\dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}{4}$$
$$2n-2m-1=\dfrac{1}{6}$$
$$12n-12m=7$$

**This is not possible as even - even cannot be odd**

Hence $x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}$ is valid for $\forall  n\in I$

**Lets check for third solution**

$$x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{7\pi}{24}$$
$$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{7\pi}{24}=\dfrac{m\pi}{2}$$
$$12n-12m=7$$

**This is not possible as even - even cannot be odd**

$$x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{7\pi}{24}$$
$$\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{7\pi}{24}=\dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}{4}$$
$$2n-2m-1=\dfrac{7}{6}$$
$$12n-12m=13$$

**This is not possible as even - even cannot be odd**

Hence $x=\dfrac{n\pi}{2}+\dfrac{7\pi}{24}$ is valid for $\forall  n\in I$

But actual answer is $x=\dfrac{n\pi}{4}+(-1)^n\dfrac{\pi}{8} \text { or } x=\dfrac{n\pi}{4}+(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{\pi}{24}$

Comment: How did you get $\;\tan2x-\dfrac{1}{\tan2x}=0\;$ at line no 5 of your computation?

Comment: yeah I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x_1=\dfrac{n\pi}{4}+(-1)^n\dfrac{\pi}{8}$ and $x_2=\dfrac{n\pi}{4}+(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{\pi}{24}$ are just compact ways to express the same answers.

If $n=2m$ is even, the roots become,

$$x_1=\dfrac{2m\pi}{4}+(-1)^{2m}\dfrac{\pi}{8}=\dfrac{m\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}$$
$$x_2=\dfrac{2m\pi}{4}+(-1)^{2m+1}\dfrac{\pi}{24}=\dfrac{2m\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\pi}{24}$$

If $n=2m+1$ is even, the roots become,

$$x_1=\dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}{4}+(-1)^{2m+1}\dfrac{\pi}{8}
=\dfrac{m\pi}{2}+\frac\pi4-\dfrac{\pi}{8}=\dfrac{m\pi}{2}+\dfrac{\pi}{8}$$
$$x_2=\dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}{4}+(-1)^{2m+2}\dfrac{\pi}{24}
=\dfrac{2m\pi}{4}+\frac\pi4+\dfrac{\pi}{24}=\dfrac{2m\pi}{4}+\dfrac{7\pi}{24}$$

Thus, they are the same as what you obtained.

Comment: thanks so much, it was good.

Comment: @user3290550 - glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that we can rewrite $\tan^2(2x)+\cot^2(2x)+2\tan(2x)+2\cot(2x)=6$ as $\tan^2(2x)+\frac{1}{\tan^2(2x)}+2\tan(2x)+\frac{2}{\tan(2x)}=6$, which can be written as one fraction by getting the denominators equal: $$\frac{\tan^4(2x)+2\tan^3(2x)+2\tan(2x)+1}{\tan^2(2x)}=6.$$
Moving the $6$ to the other side and multiply it by $\tan^2(2x)$ we get $$\frac{\tan^4(2x)+2\tan^3(2x)-6\tan^2(2x)+2\tan(2x)+1}{\tan^2(2x)}=0,$$
which implies that $\tan^4(2x)+2\tan^3(2x)-6\tan^2(2x)+2\tan(2x)+1=0$. Now, let $u:=\tan^2(2x)$ and our problem is to solve the polynomial equation $u^4+2u^3-6u^2+2u+1$.  By the rational zero theorem, a binomial factor of the form $u-b$ must have $b$ be a factor of the constant term ($1$). Testing $\pm 1$ shows that $u-1$ is a factor of our polynomial. Dividing our polynomial by $u-1$ gives us $$u^4+2u^3-6u^2+2u+1=(u^3+3u^2-3u-1)(u-1)=0.$$
We repeat this process again to yield the factored form of our polynomial $$(u+2-\sqrt{3})(u+2+\sqrt{3})(u-1)^2=0,$$
which means that $u=-2\pm\sqrt{3}$ and $u=1$ implying that we are looking for the values of $x$ such that $\tan(2x)=-2+\sqrt{3}$, $\tan(2x)=-2-\sqrt{3}$, or $\tan(2x)=1$.

#### Case 1 ($\tan(2x)=1$)

Let us handle the simplest case, $\tan(2x)=1$, first. Let $\alpha:=2x$ then $\tan(\alpha)=1$ and $\alpha=\tan^{-1}(1)=\pi/4$. Since tangent is positive in both quadrants one and three, the two solutions, $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, are $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ respectively. Or, in terms of $x$, the two solutions for this case are 
$$
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n\right),\\
x &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}+\pi n\right),
\end{align*}
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is the period offset. Notice that $x$ is multipled by a factor of one half since $\alpha=2x\implies x=\alpha/2$.

#### Case 2 ($\tan(2x)=-2+\sqrt{3}$)

Once again, let $\beta$ denote the principle angle of $\tan(2x)$. We note that $\tan(\beta)=|-2+\sqrt{3}| \implies \beta=\tan^{-1}(|-2+\sqrt{3}|)=\pi/12$. Since tangent is negative in both quadrants two and four, $\beta$ must be offset. The two solutions, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, are $11\pi/12$ and $23\pi/12$. In terms of $x$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}+\pi n\right),\\
x &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{23\pi}{12}+\pi n\right).
\end{align*}
$$

#### Case 3 ($\tan(2x)=-2-\sqrt{3}$)

Let $\gamma$ denote the principle angle of $\tan(2x)$. We note that $\tan(\gamma)=|-2-\sqrt{3}|\implies\gamma=\tan^{-1}(|-2-\sqrt{3}|)=5\pi/12$. Since tangent is negative in both quadrants two and four, $\gamma$ must be offset. The two solutions, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, are $7\pi/12$ and $19\pi/12$ respectively. In terms of $x$, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}+\pi n\right),\\
x &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{19\pi}{12}+\pi n\right).
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore, the solutions are 
$$
x= \phi+\frac{\pi n}{2}, \;\;\text{where}\;\; \phi\in\left\{\frac{\pi}{8},\frac{5\pi}{8},\frac{11\pi}{24},\frac{23\pi}{24},\frac{7\pi}{24},\frac{19\pi}{24}\right\}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way

$\tan2x+\cot2x=\cdots=2\csc4x=2y$(say)

$\tan^22x+\cot^22x=(2y)^2-2$

So, we have $$4y^2-2+4y=6$$

$$(y+2)(y-1)=0$$

If $\csc4x=1\iff\sin4x=?,4x=2n\pi+\pi/2$

If $\csc4x=-2,\sin4x=?,4x=m\pi+(-1)^m(-\pi/6)$